# I can't upload the app to google play

Tags: android

I bought an application but when I upload it to the google play this message appears

[image]

I have searched a lot and nothing has worked out. I would like some help

Answer (score 0):

You have to make build with keystore used to make build which is currently live on developer console.

Comment: I dont understand you , what can I do

Comment: when you generate signed apk in android studio you have to give path of keystore right?

Comment: give the path of that keystore with which you have generated previous apk which is live on your account

Answer (score 0):

WHen you say you bought an application, do you mean you bought an application already on the play store?  If so, they should have given you the signing key and passwords.  Use that to sign your app.  If they didn't, you need to get it from them.  If they don't have it, you need to contact google.  Good luck with that, as you'll need to prove somehow you're the new owner.  You really better hope they gave you or have the key.

Answer (score 0):

Problem : maybe you not chose the signatures v1 v2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhIqB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the key you generated the apk with is not to the one it should have, so you made some mistake at generating the signed apk in Android Studio by missing your key file. So you maybe just created a new one instead of using the old one

Answer (score 0):

You have not signed the application with a different .keystore file.

If you are using xamarin the keystore file path;
C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore

if you are using android studio, you must find your previous keystore.jks file. This file must have same md5 your error said.

You can see your keystore files md5 and sha1 codes with this command;
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore **"%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"** -alias **youralias**-storepass **yourkey**-keypass **yourkey**